# how can i give button tint to this radio group,i dont have radio button in my xml only a group

Tags: android

How can i set button tint to this radio group

```
 RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[answerOption.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < answerOption.size(); i++) {
        rb[i] = new RadioButton(getContext());

        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setText(answerOption.get(i).trim());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rb[i].setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: can you tell me how to set the text of these radio buttons to the left of the radio button